# Fetch as Google ignores my hashtag url

Tags: seo, google-search

I have an AngularJS web application:

[www.webisports.com](http://www.webisports.com)

I am using `ng-router`, so all my pages have # in the url.
I want google to index my `/#/forum page`. 
This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications) explains how to make AngularJS indexed by Google:

> To generate real URLs in Angular, rather than # prefixed ones, set HTML5 mode on your $locationProvider object: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
>
> Since you are using real URLs, you will need to ensure the same template (plus some precomposed content) gets shipped by your server for all valid URLs. How you do this will vary depending on your server architecture.

I followed this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) to make it work.

As mentioned in the article above, my server should respond to `/forum` requests, so I redirect the request from `/forum` to `/#/forum` and use HTML5 to change the url back to `/forum`. This works as expected.

My problem is with Fetch as Google. When I try to fetch the page `/forum` as Google, it tells me that this page is redirected to `/#/forum` (obviously). and when I try to fetch `/#/forum`, Google ignores the # and everything after it and fetches `/`.

How do I fetch my `/forum` page?
And how do I make sure Google indexes it?

Answer (score 1):

The `#` in a URL represents a specific part of the resource to link to. In an HTML document, for instance, it describes the ID of the element (and browsers will scroll to it).

The `#` and the data after it as never sent to the server. They are handled purely client side.

In the bad old days, single page applications used the data after the `#` to fake having distinct pages.

- The browser asks for `/`, and it gets the homepage.
- The browser asks for `/#!foo` and it gets the homepage, and then some JavaScript runs which transforms it into a different page.

This is, obviously, bad food for search engines (although, these days, search engines tend to be better at coping with that type of hack).

Then the History API came along and `pushState` allowed the local part of a URL to be changed without actually loading a new page. This allows JavaScript on the page to transform the content to `/foo` without loading `/foo` from the server from scratch.

The idea is, that when you do that, you also set up the server so it can deliver `/foo` from scratch. This gives you a page that:

- loads directly without flashing up the homepage
- works [when the JS fails](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html)
- provides good food for search engines

You are just redirecting people back to the homepage and trusting the JS to populate all the content. You should make the server deliver a real page instead.

Comment: But how do I combine it with the angularJS framework? I use the angular's routing system. it controls the routing. I only have 1 html page, and a lot of templates of html that the angularjs "replaces" in the main div when the client is changing pages.

Comment: You set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to generate real URLs on the client … and the rest is up to your server side code (which is independent to angular).

Comment: There main problem is that there is no forum html page. In angularJS there is one page with a "main" div that switches content when the client is changing pages. so basiclly i have no forum page to return when someone is asking the server for the forum page. the only thing I can return is the main page with the #/forum - which tells the angular's routing system to change the route to the forum page. and thats why if you surf to /forum you see the forum page.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Implementing this robustly would require that you create one.

Comment: So for Google to fully index my angularjs app I need to create a page duplicate to every page On my app? I hardly believe this is the only solution. There must be a way for google to index my angularjs pages without this workaround.